# Internally Multiply all pd.dataframe rows based on multiple conditions pt.2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** This is a follow up to [Internally Multiply all pd.dataframe rows based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74981680/internally-multiply-all-pd-dataframe-rows-based-on-multiple-conditions/74981874?noredirect=1#comment132328426_74981874)
For this, there is a difference in the dataset that prevents the indexing on the answer to the previous question to be used.

**Dataframe example** (this is imported with Pandas from a xlsx file):

```
Model    Scenario    Region  Variable     Unit    Year1    Year2    ...    Year50
  1        Base        1        GDP      M USD     10       15               20  
  1        Base        2        GDP      M USD     30       35               50  
  1        Base        3        GDP      M USD     20       75               80  
  1        Stress 1    1       GDP 1     % diff    0.48    0.11             0.31  
  1        Stress 1    2       GDP 2     % diff    0.12    0.33             0.89  
  1        Stress 1    3     GDP Comb    % diff    0.76    0.54             0.08  
  1        Stress 2    1       GDP 1     % diff    0.37    0.94             0.13  
  1        Stress 2    2       GDP 2     % diff    0.73    0.76             0.35  
  1        Stress 2    3     GDP Comb    % diff    0.15    0.45             0.37  
  1        Stress 3    1       GDP 1     % diff    0.49    0.14             0.37  
  1        Stress 3    2       GDP 2     % diff    0.14    0.73             0.94  
  1        Stress 3    3     GDP Comb    % diff    0.96    0.26             0.85
```

**Obs:** Each of the stress scenarios are % changes over the base scenario (for the same region). Differently from the linked post, the names of the variables are not an exact match between the stress and base scenarios (the number of rows is also different between a given stress scenario and the base scenario). The formula is base value * (1 + the stress value).

**Obs2:** The original dataframe has more models, scenarios, regions and variables, but they are always the same (all models have the same set of scenarios, all scenarios have the same set of regions and so on).

**Objective:** Is to have the values for each row to be in the same unit as baseline. For that I need to perform the multiplication mentioned above.

The formula would be:

```
Model    Scenario    ...    Year1          Year2    ...     Year50
  1      Stress 1        10*(1+0.48)    15*(1+0.11)        20*(1+0.31)
```

The output would be:

```
Model    Scenario    ...    Year1          Year2    ...     Year50
  1      Stress 1           14.8           16.65             26.2
```

**What I already tried:** I am trying to use the df.loc function to find the matching values and use them to do the calculation:

```
test_df.loc[((test_df['Model'] == '1') & (test_df['Scenario'] == 'Stress1') & (test_df['Region'] == "1") & (test_df['Variable'] == 'GDP'))] = test_df.loc[((test_df['Model'] == '1') & (test_df['Scenario'] == 'Base') & (test_df['Region'] == "1") & (test_df['Variable'] == 'GDP'))] * (1 + test_df.loc[((test_df['Model'] == '1') & (test_df['Scenario'] == 'Stress1') & (test_df['Region'] == "1") & (test_df['Variable'] == 'GDP'))])
```

**Obs3:** Apparently this kind of multi conditional operation is not ideal, and an indexing based multiplication is better. This operation was the answer to the linked question.

**Current solution:** From the linked post, the solution is:

```
years = [Year1,Year2,Year50]
df1 = (test_df[(test_df['Scenario'] == 'Base')]
             .set_index(['Model','Region','Variable'])[years])
df2 = (test_df[(test_df['Unit'] == '% diff')]
             .set_index(['Model','Scenario','Region','Variable','Unit'])[years])
df = df2.add(1).mul(df1).reset_index()
```

**Question:** How can this snippet be improved to account for the mismatch in the "Variable" column between the scenarios?

**Update:** Uploaded a sample dataset for reference. https://www.mediafire.com/file/n18z2mizylu3fzz/Sample_data_for_df_multiplication.xlsx/file

Comment: real data are larger?

Comment: @jezrael the sample is just and example of the dataset. The dataset included in the last update contains multiple models, scenarios, variables, regions and so on.

Comment: What is `print (len(df1['Variable'].drop_duplicates()))` in real data? In sample it is 33

Comment: @jezrael its 1101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is if create MultiIndex in `df1` also by `Variable` it not match with `Variable` values in `df2` and ouput is `NaN`:

Here is solution for match `Variable` values from `df1['Variable']` to `df2['Variable']` by matching with subtstrings:

```
test_df = pd.read_excel('Sample data for df multiplication.xlsx').iloc[:, :10]
    
df1 = test_df.loc[(test_df['Scenario'] == 'Baseline')].copy()
df2 = test_df[test_df['Unit'].str.contains("% diff")].copy()

#for me not working well - some valeus not match
# pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in df1['Variable'].unique())
# df2['Variable1'] = df2['Variable'].str.extract(rf'({pat})', expand=False)

#testing without regex working weell in sample data
for x in df1['Variable'].unique():
    df2.loc[df2['Variable'].str.contains(x, regex=False), 'Variable1'] = x


years = ['2022','2023','2024']

df1 = df1.set_index(['Model','Region','Variable'])[years]
df2 = df2.set_index(['Model','Scenario','Region','Variable1','Unit'])[years]


df = df2.add(1).mul(df1).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the solution where "Variable" is ommited, should it also be removed from the line that indexes df2?

Comment: @DGMS89 No, it is not necessary remove in df2.

Comment: @DGMS89 - Answer was edited by sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do get the result your question describes:

```py
years = [col for col in test_df.columns if col.startswith('Year')]
regionAndYears = ['Region'] + years
df_base = test_df.loc[df.Scenario=='Base', regionAndYears].set_index('Region')
scenarioMask = test_df.Scenario != 'Base'
test_df.loc[scenarioMask, years] = ( test_df.loc[scenarioMask, regionAndYears]
    .apply(lambda row: (1 + row.reindex(years)) * df_base.loc[row.Region,:], 
    axis=1) )
```

Output:

```
    Model  Scenario  Region  Variable    Unit  Year1   Year2  Year50
0       1      Base       1       GDP   M USD   10.0   15.00    20.0
1       1      Base       2       GDP   M USD   30.0   35.00    50.0
2       1      Base       3       GDP   M USD   20.0   75.00    80.0
3       1  Stress 1       1     GDP 1  % diff   14.8   16.65    26.2
4       1  Stress 1       2     GDP 2  % diff   33.6   46.55    94.5
5       1  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb  % diff   35.2  115.50    86.4
6       1  Stress 2       1     GDP 1  % diff   13.7   29.10    22.6
7       1  Stress 2       2     GDP 2  % diff   51.9   61.60    67.5
8       1  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb  % diff   23.0  108.75   109.6
9       1  Stress 3       1     GDP 1  % diff   14.9   17.10    27.4
10      1  Stress 3       2     GDP 2  % diff   34.2   60.55    97.0
11      1  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb  % diff   39.2   94.50   148.0
```

Explanation:

- create a new dataframe `df_base` containing only the data in the columns `Year1 .. Year50` and indexed by `Region`
- for the non-Base `Scenario` rows, use `apply()` to perform the desired calculation on the values in the Base row in `df_base` with matching `Region`.

---

**UPDATE:**

As a generalization of the original answer above, in response to a comment by OP asking "would this work if there are more models in the dataset", the following code will handle multiple models:

```py
baseKey = ['Model', 'Region']
years = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Year')]
baseKeyAndYears = baseKey + years
df_base = df.loc[df.Scenario=='Base', baseKeyAndYears].set_index(baseKey)
scenarioMask = df.Scenario != 'Base'
df.loc[scenarioMask, years] = ( df.loc[scenarioMask, baseKeyAndYears]
    .apply(lambda row: (1 + row.reindex(years)) * df_base.reindex(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(row[baseKey].astype(int).to_frame().T)).squeeze(),
    axis=1) )
```

Sample input:

```
    Model  Scenario  Region  Variable    Unit   Year1   Year2  Year50
0       1      Base       1       GDP   M USD   10.00   15.00   20.00
1       1      Base       2       GDP   M USD   30.00   35.00   50.00
2       1      Base       3       GDP   M USD   20.00   75.00   80.00
3       1  Stress 1       1     GDP 1  % diff    0.48    0.11    0.31
4       1  Stress 1       2     GDP 2  % diff    0.12    0.33    0.89
5       1  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb  % diff    0.76    0.54    0.08
6       1  Stress 2       1     GDP 1  % diff    0.37    0.94    0.13
7       1  Stress 2       2     GDP 2  % diff    0.73    0.76    0.35
8       1  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb  % diff    0.15    0.45    0.37
9       1  Stress 3       1     GDP 1  % diff    0.49    0.14    0.37
10      1  Stress 3       2     GDP 2  % diff    0.14    0.73    0.94
11      1  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb  % diff    0.96    0.26    0.85
12      2      Base       1       GDP   M USD  100.00  150.00  200.00
13      2      Base       2       GDP   M USD  300.00  350.00  500.00
14      2      Base       3       GDP   M USD  200.00  750.00  800.00
15      2  Stress 1       1     GDP 1  % diff    0.48    0.11    0.31
16      2  Stress 1       2     GDP 2  % diff    0.12    0.33    0.89
17      2  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb  % diff    0.76    0.54    0.08
18      2  Stress 2       1     GDP 1  % diff    0.37    0.94    0.13
19      2  Stress 2       2     GDP 2  % diff    0.73    0.76    0.35
20      2  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb  % diff    0.15    0.45    0.37
21      2  Stress 3       1     GDP 1  % diff    0.49    0.14    0.37
22      2  Stress 3       2     GDP 2  % diff    0.14    0.73    0.94
23      2  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb  % diff    0.96    0.26    0.85
```

Sample output:

```
    Model  Scenario  Region  Variable    Unit  Year1    Year2  Year50
0       1      Base       1       GDP   M USD   10.0    15.00    20.0
1       1      Base       2       GDP   M USD   30.0    35.00    50.0
2       1      Base       3       GDP   M USD   20.0    75.00    80.0
3       1  Stress 1       1     GDP 1  % diff   14.8    16.65    26.2
4       1  Stress 1       2     GDP 2  % diff   33.6    46.55    94.5
5       1  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb  % diff   35.2   115.50    86.4
6       1  Stress 2       1     GDP 1  % diff   13.7    29.10    22.6
7       1  Stress 2       2     GDP 2  % diff   51.9    61.60    67.5
8       1  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb  % diff   23.0   108.75   109.6
9       1  Stress 3       1     GDP 1  % diff   14.9    17.10    27.4
10      1  Stress 3       2     GDP 2  % diff   34.2    60.55    97.0
11      1  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb  % diff   39.2    94.50   148.0
12      2      Base       1       GDP   M USD  100.0   150.00   200.0
13      2      Base       2       GDP   M USD  300.0   350.00   500.0
14      2      Base       3       GDP   M USD  200.0   750.00   800.0
15      2  Stress 1       1     GDP 1  % diff  148.0   166.50   262.0
16      2  Stress 1       2     GDP 2  % diff  336.0   465.50   945.0
17      2  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb  % diff  352.0  1155.00   864.0
18      2  Stress 2       1     GDP 1  % diff  137.0   291.00   226.0
19      2  Stress 2       2     GDP 2  % diff  519.0   616.00   675.0
20      2  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb  % diff  230.0  1087.50  1096.0
21      2  Stress 3       1     GDP 1  % diff  149.0   171.00   274.0
22      2  Stress 3       2     GDP 2  % diff  342.0   605.50   970.0
23      2  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb  % diff  392.0   945.00  1480.0
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Here's an even more general answer that will:

- for each model

  - for each region

    - for each variable type inferred from `Variable` values (in case for example there are some `XYZ` type variables in addition to the `GDP` ones)

      - isolate the `Base` scenarios
      - isolate the non-`Base` scenarios
      - for each different value of `Unit` (in case there are some `% diff` scenarios and some other calculations, for example `additive diff`)

        - for recognized units, perform the unit's appropriate calculation on each non-`Base` scenario and its matching `Base` scenario (that is, having the same `Model, Region, Variable_type` index label)
        - for unrecognized units, set the output values to `NaN`

```py
test_df['Variable_type'] = test_df.Variable.str.partition().iloc[:,0]
key = ['Model','Region','Variable_type']
years = [col for col in test_df.columns if col.startswith('Year')]
df_base = test_df[test_df.Scenario == 'Base'].set_index(key)[years]
df_out = test_df[test_df.Scenario != 'Base'].set_index(key + ['Scenario'])
mask_pct_diff = df_out.Unit == '% diff'
mask_add_diff = df_out.Unit == 'additive diff'
mask_other_unit = ~(mask_pct_diff | mask_add_diff)
df_out.loc[mask_pct_diff, years] = df_out.loc[mask_pct_diff, years].add(1).mul(df_base)
df_out.loc[mask_add_diff, years] = df_out.loc[mask_add_diff, years].add(df_base)
df_out.loc[mask_other_unit, years] = None
test_df = test_df.drop(columns='Variable_type')
df_out = df_out.assign(Variable=df_out.Variable).reset_index()[test_df.columns]
```

Sample input:

```
    Model  Scenario  Region  Variable           Unit    Year1    Year2   Year50
0       1      Base       1       GDP          M USD   10.000   15.000   20.000
1       1      Base       2       GDP          M USD   30.000   35.000   50.000
2       1      Base       3       GDP          M USD   20.000   75.000   80.000
3       1  Stress 1       1     GDP 1         % diff    0.480    0.110    0.310
4       1  Stress 1       2     GDP 2         % diff    0.120    0.330    0.890
5       1  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb         % diff    0.760    0.540    0.080
6       1  Stress 2       1     GDP 1         % diff    0.370    0.940    0.130
7       1  Stress 2       2     GDP 2         % diff    0.730    0.760    0.350
8       1  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb         % diff    0.150    0.450    0.370
9       1  Stress 3       1     GDP 1         % diff    0.490    0.140    0.370
10      1  Stress 3       2     GDP 2         % diff    0.140    0.730    0.940
11      1  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb         % diff    0.960    0.260    0.850
12      1  Stress 4       1  GDP Plus  additive diff    1.111    1.222    1.333
13      1      Base       1       XYZ          M USD  -10.000  -15.000  -20.000
14      1      Base       2       XYZ          M USD  -30.000  -35.000  -50.000
15      1      Base       3       XYZ          M USD  -20.000  -75.000  -80.000
16      1  Stress 1       1     XYZ 1         % diff    0.100    0.200    0.300
17      1  Stress 1       2     XYZ 2         % diff    0.110    0.210    0.310
18      1  Stress 1       3  XYZ Comb         % diff    0.120    0.220    0.310
19      1  Stress 2       1     XYZ 1         % diff    0.130    0.230    0.320
20      1  Stress 2       2     XYZ 2         % diff    0.140    0.240    0.330
21      1  Stress 2       3  XYZ Comb         % diff    0.140    0.250    0.340
22      1  Stress 3       1     XYZ 1         % diff    0.160    0.260    0.350
23      1  Stress 3       2     XYZ 2         % diff    0.170    0.270    0.360
24      1  Stress 3       3  XYZ Comb         % diff    0.180    0.280    0.370
25      1  Stress 4       1  XYZ Plus  additive diff    2.111    2.222    2.333
26      2      Base       1       GDP          M USD  100.000  150.000  200.000
27      2      Base       2       GDP          M USD  300.000  350.000  500.000
28      2      Base       3       GDP          M USD  200.000  750.000  800.000
29      2  Stress 1       1     GDP 1         % diff    0.480    0.110    0.310
30      2  Stress 1       2     GDP 2         % diff    0.120    0.330    0.890
31      2  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb         % diff    0.760    0.540    0.080
32      2  Stress 2       1     GDP 1         % diff    0.370    0.940    0.130
33      2  Stress 2       2     GDP 2         % diff    0.730    0.760    0.350
34      2  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb         % diff    0.150    0.450    0.370
35      2  Stress 3       1     GDP 1         % diff    0.490    0.140    0.370
36      2  Stress 3       2     GDP 2         % diff    0.140    0.730    0.940
37      2  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb         % diff    0.960    0.260    0.850
38      2  Stress 4       1  GDP Plus  additive diff    3.111    4.222    4.333
39      2      Base       1       XYZ          M USD -100.000 -150.000 -200.000
40      2      Base       2       XYZ          M USD -300.000 -350.000 -500.000
41      2      Base       3       XYZ          M USD -200.000 -750.000 -800.000
42      2  Stress 1       1     XYZ 1         % diff    0.105    0.205    0.305
43      2  Stress 1       2     XYZ 2         % diff    0.115    0.215    0.315
44      2  Stress 1       3  XYZ Comb         % diff    0.125    0.225    0.315
45      2  Stress 2       1     XYZ 1         % diff    0.135    0.235    0.325
46      2  Stress 2       2     XYZ 2         % diff    0.145    0.245    0.335
47      2  Stress 2       3  XYZ Comb         % diff    0.145    0.255    0.345
48      2  Stress 3       1     XYZ 1         % diff    0.165    0.265    0.355
49      2  Stress 3       2     XYZ 2         % diff    0.175    0.275    0.365
50      2  Stress 3       3  XYZ Comb         % diff    0.185    0.285    0.375
51      2  Stress 4       1  XYZ Plus  additive diff    4.111    4.222    4.333
```

Sample output:

```
    Model  Scenario  Region  Variable           Unit    Year1     Year2    Year50
0       1  Stress 1       1     GDP 1         % diff   14.800    16.650    26.200
1       1  Stress 1       2     GDP 2         % diff   33.600    46.550    94.500
2       1  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb         % diff   35.200   115.500    86.400
3       1  Stress 2       1     GDP 1         % diff   13.700    29.100    22.600
4       1  Stress 2       2     GDP 2         % diff   51.900    61.600    67.500
5       1  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb         % diff   23.000   108.750   109.600
6       1  Stress 3       1     GDP 1         % diff   14.900    17.100    27.400
7       1  Stress 3       2     GDP 2         % diff   34.200    60.550    97.000
8       1  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb         % diff   39.200    94.500   148.000
9       1  Stress 4       1  GDP Plus  additive diff   11.111    16.222    21.333
10      1  Stress 1       1     XYZ 1         % diff  -11.000   -18.000   -26.000
11      1  Stress 1       2     XYZ 2         % diff  -33.300   -42.350   -65.500
12      1  Stress 1       3  XYZ Comb         % diff  -22.400   -91.500  -104.800
13      1  Stress 2       1     XYZ 1         % diff  -11.300   -18.450   -26.400
14      1  Stress 2       2     XYZ 2         % diff  -34.200   -43.400   -66.500
15      1  Stress 2       3  XYZ Comb         % diff  -22.800   -93.750  -107.200
16      1  Stress 3       1     XYZ 1         % diff  -11.600   -18.900   -27.000
17      1  Stress 3       2     XYZ 2         % diff  -35.100   -44.450   -68.000
18      1  Stress 3       3  XYZ Comb         % diff  -23.600   -96.000  -109.600
19      1  Stress 4       1  XYZ Plus  additive diff   -7.889   -12.778   -17.667
20      2  Stress 1       1     GDP 1         % diff  148.000   166.500   262.000
21      2  Stress 1       2     GDP 2         % diff  336.000   465.500   945.000
22      2  Stress 1       3  GDP Comb         % diff  352.000  1155.000   864.000
23      2  Stress 2       1     GDP 1         % diff  137.000   291.000   226.000
24      2  Stress 2       2     GDP 2         % diff  519.000   616.000   675.000
25      2  Stress 2       3  GDP Comb         % diff  230.000  1087.500  1096.000
26      2  Stress 3       1     GDP 1         % diff  149.000   171.000   274.000
27      2  Stress 3       2     GDP 2         % diff  342.000   605.500   970.000
28      2  Stress 3       3  GDP Comb         % diff  392.000   945.000  1480.000
29      2  Stress 4       1  GDP Plus  additive diff  103.111   154.222   204.333
30      2  Stress 1       1     XYZ 1         % diff -110.500  -180.750  -261.000
31      2  Stress 1       2     XYZ 2         % diff -334.500  -425.250  -657.500
32      2  Stress 1       3  XYZ Comb         % diff -225.000  -918.750 -1052.000
33      2  Stress 2       1     XYZ 1         % diff -113.500  -185.250  -265.000
34      2  Stress 2       2     XYZ 2         % diff -343.500  -435.750  -667.500
35      2  Stress 2       3  XYZ Comb         % diff -229.000  -941.250 -1076.000
36      2  Stress 3       1     XYZ 1         % diff -116.500  -189.750  -271.000
37      2  Stress 3       2     XYZ 2         % diff -352.500  -446.250  -682.500
38      2  Stress 3       3  XYZ Comb         % diff -237.000  -963.750 -1100.000
39      2  Stress 4       1  XYZ Plus  additive diff  -95.889  -145.778  -195.667
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question: would this work if there are more models in the dataset?

Comment: My original answer was not designed to handle multiple models (only the single model shown in your question), but I have updated my answer to include a generalization of the original logic that will handle multiple models.

Comment: I made a second update which handles multiple `Model, Region, Variable_type (inferred from Variable), Unit` combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Assuming that the final result is in df_out, it does not seem to be performing the calculation, as the result of non base scenarios is still the original % difference values of test_df. I believe this is related to an issue observed in the previous post, where the variable unit field contains "% diff" and other variations of it (e.g. '% difference"). I tried solving it by changing the mask to: mask_pct_diff = df_out['Unit'].str.contains("% diff") but that generates a ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: My answer assumes `Unit` is as shown in your question, namely `% diff`. I then expanded this assumption to include an example of rows containing a different `Unit` value of `additive diff`. Just now, I added logic to null out the output values for rows containing unrecognized `Unit` values. If your actual data contains such unrecognized unit values, that sounds like a data standardization issue that needs to be addressed but is somewhat separate from the focus of your original question. If `% difference` is the only example of a deviation, your `contains` works in my environment.

Comment: Do you need additional help with your original question?

Comment: If you don't need more help, please consider marking one of the answers "accepted",